# Command to detach Surface Book screen

Tags: windows-10, display, powershell, cmd.exe, microsoft-surface

My surface book keyboard is dying :(

Keys 1,2,3,4, z,x,c,v and Enter enter multiple characters (e.g. 1 => 123) and the hard detach screen key is not working.

I have cleaned the contacts, rebooted etc. not helped. Just moved countries so have not been able to send for repair (and just out of warranty).

Current issue is I have turned screen away from keyboard. The device is in tablet mode with external keyboard and mouse. I cannot detach the keyboard (no hard or soft detach button).

Is there a PowerShell or EXE that I can run to detach the screen? My google-fu has not managed to find one. Can you help?

Comment: Reaching out to MS via Twitter resulted in the following ... any of you know better? "... There is no command line that you can use to detach the keyboard on your Surface Book. You can check this article for more details: http://msft.social/ns0dBo  ..."

Comment: Do you not have Surface Detach running in your notification tray?

Comment: It disappeared when I turned the screen around and re-attached. Think it missed that I had reattached so thought was not attached. Temp fix was to force in settings that it should always use Desktop mode and reboot.

Comment: For future readers - in the end I bought a bluetooth keyboard and use that with the screen turned round. Error is on the keyboard unit as swapped at shop and shop one worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the surface book 1s were released with a quite dull and irritating manufacturer[-denied] defect.

I’ve already contacted Microsoft; trust me, when situations such as these arise, they are not looking to help you out of the goodness of their hearts, because, well— they get paid whether we, the customers, are happy or not.

I’m not sure if you were determined as I was, but if you are trying to detach the Microsoft book from the base, your solution will likely not lie internally, but rather externally. Grab yourself a handy paper clip, you’re going to need it.

On each side of your surface book computer case, there should be a small indentation with a plethora of holes for ventilation. Find these on both sides of your screen.

Now, starting from your base (keyboard), count six (6) holes up. Insert the paper clip and push — these are where the base clips are located. The base clips are in their own compartments; depressing the paper clip will require some force, but not as much to be alarmed.

[image: paperclip insertion location]

If you are doing this for the first time, I would suggest depressing both sides. I have created a small “tool”— a contraption consisting of an earring, a broken needle and a pen part— to allow me to detach my screen periodically.

[image: contraption]

Keep in mind, though — if your detach process is not working, there is most likely something wrong with the battery in the screen. You might notice a slight bulge in your screen— this is where the manufacturer denies their mistakes, as most individuals have a slightly bloated surface book screen/case.

Now, due to the battery not working— your surface book will most likely completely shut down, leading to alarm and reboot.
No, you didn’t break it, it’s just a crappy laptop. Hitting it won’t help, but I can’t say that for sure.
Be safe, yo!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detail Jackson. In the end I used brute force to pull it apart ... base unit pretty much dead. Now prop main unit with charger into its bottom. Battery is blowing too (apparently they use the battery as heat sink ... wat!) so looks like need to upgrade laptop very soon.